# Why does dynamic linking work when I use -lc with my.s?

Tags: c, linux, glibc, dynamic-linking

If I compile the below with `gcc -g a.c -lz -o normal` and execute it on my debian server, it complains with

> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./normal)

However if I compile with `gcc -g a.c -lz -lc -nostdlib my.s -o alt` I can execute it on that server without it complaining. Why? Can I do this without writing my own start function? I don't understand much assembly my friend wrote that assembly

a.c

```
#include <zlib.h>
int main() {
    z_stream s;
    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(z_stream));
    return deflateInit(&s, 7);
}
```

my.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
    call main
    mov %rax, %rdi
    mov $60, %rax
    syscall
```

Comment: Also, what is the actual purpose of the assembler part in this?

Comment: @TedLyngmo mixing a.c/main.c was a typo. The assembler is because gcc complained about _start

Comment: I see. It seems like a hack that should have a simpler solution. What if you specify `-lc` too? Like this: `gcc -g a.c -lz -lc -o normal`

Comment: Btw, you've forgotten `#include <string.h>` in `a.c`

Answer (score 0):

> If I compile the below with `gcc -g a.c -lz -o normal` and execute it on my debian server, it complains with

This is working as intended -- you can not "compile / link against newer GLIBC, run against older GLIBC".

Instead of trying hacks, you should set a proper development environment targeting your older Debian system. This is usually achieved by using a `chroot` or a container.

> However if I compile with `gcc -g a.c -lz -lc -nostdlib my.s -o alt` I can execute it on that server without it complaining. Why?

You've bypassed GLIBC startup code, which depended on something that the older GLIBC on Debian doesn't provide.

While this hack appears to work for your simple program, it *will* break once you start using more of libc facilities (`stdio`, threads, etc.). The GLIBC startup code is there *for a reason*, and when you bypass it all kinds of things could (and will) break.

Just Don't Do It(TM).

Comment: Before applying "Just Don't Do It(TM)." I'd like to know, wouldn't the dynamic loader be initing the older glibc? So it'd be ok? I may write a unit test for my use cases but for the most part I can stick with nostdlib+static